# Save bitmap image in the subimagefolder based on the name

Tags: c#, bitmap, save, jpeg, store

In my code I have created an image folder and in the image folder I again created a sub folder. I have downloaded a static google map image from url. I want to save it in the sub folder according to the location name. But it is not saving in the subfolder it saves in the image folder.Also it is showing location name in front of the image name. but I only need the hash code. not the file name. Here is my code which I used to download and store the image

```
public static void Map(string LocationName)
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {

        var client = new WebClient();

        var startPath = Application.StartupPath;
        string Imagefolder = Path.Combine(startPath, "Image");
        string subImageFolder = Path.Combine(Imagefolder, LocationName);
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subImageFolder);
        string Jpeg = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, subImageFolder);

        var uri = ("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + LocationName + "&zoom=9&size=300x200&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false");
        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);

        HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream imageStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
        Bitmap buddyIcon = new Bitmap(imageStream);
        httpResponse.Close();
        imageStream.Close();
        Image2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

        //Load Image
        Image2.Image = buddyIcon;
        var hash = uri.GetHashCode();
        buddyIcon.Save(Jpeg + hash.ToString("X") + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

Comment: buddyIcon.Save(Path.combine(jpeg, hash.ToString("X") + ".jpg"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg); could you try that? I am without a pc at the moment to test your code.

Comment: Thank a lot. It solves the problem. @SimonWilson